Blazor Web App default sample deployed to AWS fargate Counter page is not connecting to _blazor consistently
The basic blazor sample page included 3 pages. Home, Counter and Weather.
If I go to the counter the page, I am given the below response most of the time.
Description of error
[2024-07-16T18:04:33.238Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://web-ap-recip-wcukoujlrx9p-788395437.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/_blazor'.
WebSocket connection to 'ws://web-ap-recip-wcukoujlrx9p-788395437.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/_blazor?id=ZJQGcwycWIoW-NNc8DumoA' failed: (anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
[2024-07-16T18:04:33.565Z] Information: (WebSockets transport) There was an error with the transport.
blazor.web.js:1
[2024-07-16T18:04:33.566Z]
Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets':
Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
log @ blazor.web.js:1
blazor?id=9bpMXJLhcbcmRWuxqi7QqQ&=1721153073659:1
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[2024-07-16T18:04:33.754Z] Error: Failed to start the transport 'LongPolling': Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'
log @ blazor.web.js:1
[2024-07-16T18:04:33.754Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports. Error: WebSockets failed: Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled. ServerSentEvents failed: Error: 'ServerSentEvents' does not support Binary.
Error: LongPolling failed: Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'
log @ blazor.web.js:1
[2024-07-16T18:04:33.754Z] Error: Error: Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports. Error: WebSockets failed: Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled. ServerSentEvents failed: Error: 'ServerSentEvents' does not support Binary. Error: LongPolling failed: Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code '404'
log @ blazor.web.js:1
[2024-07-16T18:04:33.754Z] Error: Unable to connect, please ensure WebSockets are available. A VPN or proxy may be blocking the connection.
log @ blazor.web.js:1
[2024-07-16T18:04:33.754Z] Error: Failed to start the circuit.
However, if I refresh or reload the page multiple times eventually, I am able to reach the server and establish a connection with SignalIR. Although, if I leave the page, the _blazor/disconnect fails to load.
Successful Connection
[2024-07-16T18:07:58.431Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://web-ap-recip-wcukoujlrx9p-788395437.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/_blazor'.
[2024-07-16T18:07:58.899Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://web-ap-recip-wcukoujlrx9p-788395437.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/_blazor?id=MkIoe5VDiDts4Z5d1X6Dqg.
blazor.web.js:1
[2024-07-16T18:09:04.819Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
blazor.web.js:1
    POST http://web-ap-recip-wcukoujlrx9p-788395437.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/_blazor/disconnect net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)

I have been googling and AI checking all the different errors to see if anyone else has had this issue and have found that when this issue in relation to blazor is infrequent. I am also working with my team to see if there is a timeout issue with AWS or Signal to see if it will work.

Since I cannot reproduce it locally, you could follow this discussion to get more information. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45484  The issue could be caused by various reasons, and the first thing is to change log level to get more log details to help us narrow down the issue.

Some steps need to check, first, why don't use https? Second, have you applied any identity part? Third, have you enabled sticky sessions, if not please try and check.

@FengzhiZhou didn't know it wasn't know it wasn't using https. I am not using any microsoft identity technology. I had set the Authenticator to None. I do not have sticky sessions enabled.

@FengzhiZhou I will google how to do that and if I can't figure it out I will ask here if you don't mind.
